# What is Windows Installer and do I need it for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer

What is Windows Installer and do I need it for Windows XP?

Answer (score 5):

[Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) is the standard program for installing windows software.

It is required for any windows updates to be installed.

Also, a large proportion of windows software requires it in order to install.

So yes, you need it.

Comment: How can one knw which version is installed and if I want to [update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8483) which file do I need to download I don't get should i download all or none